# Одинаковая высота сайта при всех разрешениях

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возможно ли вообще сделать так, чтобы высота сайта была фиксированная и не нужно было пользоваться вертикальным скроллом. 
Т.е. сайт будет как адаптивное изображение.
Просьба описать решение хотя бы в общих чертах.

Comment: Да. Прижимаете футер к низу. Шапку по желанию. Весь контент ограничиваете высотой которая должна выщитываться - Высота видимой части экрана - высота футера - высота шапки. По желанию отступы учитывать и т.д.

Comment: делаете все как сказано выше но еще одно уточнение все размеры должны быть в % исходя из того что body100%

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/elegant-grey-illumination-background-presentations-powerpoint-backgrounds.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Блок контейнер всегда будет соответствовать высоте окна браузера, по большому случаю, здесь даже и не требуется абсолютное позиционирование, так как размер указан в "vh"